# Find previous cell address (to the left) in active row with different value than active cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I,ve tried to find a VBA solution for finding the previous cell (located on the same row) with different value than the selected cell has. So if the selected cell is for example [N6] (as in my picture) then my search range should be ("A6:N6") from which I need to find the last cell with a different cell value (which would be cell [L6] in my picture because it's the previous cell with a different value than cell [N6]. The search should start from the end (N6,M6,L6...) backwards until the first match is found (first different cell value). When the first match is found then select it. I have hundreds of columns, so my picture is just to show the principle. I execute my vba code with `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` so when the user selects a cell with the mouse. I get the desired cell with `{=ADDRESS(6;MATCH(2;1/(A6:O6<>"D")))}` but I would need a VBA solution for my problem. My current VBA solution takes me to cell [I6] instead of [L6] and I can't figure out how to edit my code to find the correct cell ([L6] in my example picture).

```
Dim rngSel As String, rngStart As String
Dim rngActiveStart As Range
rngSel = ActiveCell.Address(0, 0)
rngStart = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Address(0, 0)
Set rngActiveStart = Range(rngStart & ":" & rngSel)

Dim c
    For Each c In rngActiveStart.Cells        
        If c <> Target.Value And c.Offset(0, 1) = Target.Value Then
                c.Select
                MsgBox "Previous different cell: " & c.Address(0, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

[image]

Comment: you need to select an answer so the thread shows as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Using selection_Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Long, col As Long, x
    Dim v As String
    
    r = Target.Row
    v = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For x = Target.Column To 1 Step -1

        With Me
            If .Cells(r, x) <> v Then
                .Cells(r, x).Select
                Exit For
            End If
        End With

    Next x

    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to `Exit For`  after `.Select` otherwise this will always check until column A and therefore the result in this example will be A6 is selected and not as desired L6, because A6 is the last cell checked and it is different from N6 where we started. And `EnableEvents` is `Boolean` not `Integer` you should use `True/False` also in VBA `True` is `-1` check `Debug.Print Int(True)`, if you use numerics here you have an unnecessary implicit type conversion from `Integer` to `Boolean`. Finally `x As Long`.

Comment: And `v` should probably be `Variant` just in case there are no strings in these cells but other value types (unnecessary type conversions could lead to false positives here). Or kick `v` and use `.Cells(r, x) <> Target` directly. • Finally If you want the perfect solution use error handling to turn on `EnableEvents` in case of any error, otherwise you might stick in an odd case where events stay off (just in case this is a good practice to do).

Comment: I tried this but it always gives me the cell that is clicked: `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim r As Long, col As Long, x As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    
    r = Target.Row
    v = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For x = Target.Column To 1 Step -1

        With Me
            If .Cells(r, x) <> v Then .Cells(r, x).Select
            Exit For
        End With
    Next x
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    MsgBox "Previous different cell: " & Selection.Address(0, 0)

End Sub`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ-thanks peh, did not think about additional cells not equal to target.

Comment: I also thought true/1 and false/0 were the same.

Comment: @Davesexcel With formulas you are correct. As per definition in formulas `true=1, false=0` but in VBA `true=-1, false=0`. So actually the other way round if you convert numbers to boolean only `0` is considered as `False` everything else is automatically converted to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `For i = max To min Step -1` loop to loop backwards/left:

```
Public Sub MoveLeftUntilChange()
    
    Dim SelRange As Range 'remember the selected range 'N6
    Set SelRange = Selection
    
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = SelRange.Column To 1 Step -1 'move columns leftwards
        With SelRange.Parent.Cells(SelRange.Row, iCol) 'this is the current row/column to test againts the remembered range N6
            If .Value <> SelRange.Value Then 'if change found select and exit
                .Select
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next iCol
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This code does nothing for me when I click on a cell.

Comment: The code is just an example of how to do it, not a copy paste solution. Some effort of your side is needed. You need to put it into the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and replace `Selection` with `Target`